# How to get a running Jar's file path?

Tags: windows, java, process, path, jvm

When I run some jar file, the process created is an instance of the JVM, which executes the jar. How can I know what jar file a JVM process is running? I would like to use this information to retrieve said jar's file path.

Comment: [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](//stackoverflow.com/q/320542)

Comment: That post only works if you have the source code for the Jar. My case is more general. I want to find the path for any jar running on my machine, even if I don't have the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke the JAR by using the full path as the `-jar` parameter from the command line. The Task Manager can show the command line which includes the path to the JAR. Open it by running `taskmgr` from Windows search. Then do one of the following:

1. In the Processes tab, right-click the column header and enable the `Command Line` option.

OR

2. In the Details tab, right-click the column header, click Select Columns, click the `Command Line` checkbox, and click OK.

**References**

- [Configure Task Manager to Display Full Path and Command Line of Running Processes » Winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/configure-task-manager-to-display-full-path-of-running-processes/)
- [Creating the First JAR File - hello.jar](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jar-Create-First-JAR-File.html)
- [sample-apps/example-java-jar-hello at master · apcera/sample-apps · GitHub](https://github.com/apcera/sample-apps/tree/master/example-java-jar-hello)
- [Inspired by Actual Events: JAR Manifest Class-Path is Not for Java Application Launcher Only](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/09/jar-manifest-class-path-javac.html)
- [import java.* | Dr Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/import-java/184403693)
- [javase tools: jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#JSWOR614)